# *ngFor with Bootstrap Collapsible only show one data

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make collapsible using Bootstrap and Angular *ngFor loop directive. But it is only collapsing/showing the first data from my database. The button's names are already correct but when I click at them, every buttons only collapsing/showing the first button's content and the first data of database. Looks like i didn't make it work correctly, can anyone help me solve this?

```html
<div class="container" *ngFor="let List of List">
  <a href="#List" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse">{{List.prdName}}</a>
  <div id="List" class="collapse">
    <ul style="list-style: none">
      <li> {{List.prdName}}</li>
      <li> {{List.prdCategory}}</li>
      <li> {{List.prdSup}}</li>
      <li> <img src="{{List.prdImage}}"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `href` value probably needs to point to a unique `id`. You can use the index for the id. Something like this:

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let item of List; let i = index">
  <a href="#List-{{ i }}" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse">{{item.prdName}}</a>
  <div id="List-{{ i }}" class="collapse">
    <ul style="list-style: none">
      <li> {{item.prdName}}</li>
      <li> {{item.prdCategory}}</li>
      <li> {{item.prdSup}}</li>
      <li> <img src="{{item.prdImage}}"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the **List** in *ngFor="let **List** of List"* to **list**

It may work

Comment: i do not think it will, because the `List` is defined from my typescript file `List: List[] = [];`.

Comment: @WiraXie Right but the current item from the list should probably have a different name than the list itself